# How About an MVC Style Structure in an Classic ASP App?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP app that is just starting to undergo transformation into MVC.  As that might take a while, I am thinking of applying some MVC-style logic to key parts of the existing code to make day to day maintenance easier.

Firstly I plan to create a 'view' - an include file that is iterated through with every record of a GetRows().

Secondly I plan to create a 'model' - a simple property driven class to display the item.  For example a BusinessProfile class might have properties such as BusinessName, Address, PhoneNumber, and YearsInBusiness.

Finally I plan to create a 'controller' class that will grab the data (using the GetRows() method), perform any calculations required and populate the 'model'.

*Is such a task worth doing?*

*Might such an approach would cause a big performance hit in a classic asp app?  Right now most of the html is being written directly to the response stream and I understand that this is an efficient way of working in ASP.*

I did find [an article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/585883/Classic-ASP-and-MVC) which indicates the approach I'm taking, but I won't be going that far in mimicking MVC (no url changes or route data to consider).

Comment: You are not the only one to want to do this. See http://www.classicaspsquare.com/View/ASP-Square-Framework and http://simplicity.ws/.

Comment: Sorry I have to ask... Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there will be a difference in performance in Classic ASP using an MVC structure. It's simply just more work for it to do.  However, the trade-off is maintainability, depending on how big the application is, and you have to think it's worth it. I would think it is since Classic ASP is 'spaghetti code'.

To be honest, I would learn C# Asp.Net MVC5 instead.  Great tutorials online to learn to do this type of stuff pretty quickly--Developing in general is quicker in C#/.Net than in classic ASP when considering all the built in functionality offered, which helps make up for most of the time taken to learn .net. It's also worth using the effort to learn .net MVC rather than rebuilding or building a new Classic ASP application, because if you knew ASP.Net MVC, you surely wouldn't be going this route.  (I am a Classic ASP Developer)

Comment: Classic ASP is only 'Spaghetti Code' if you write it poorly.  If you separate out your code into linked modules and write the code properly you can avoid this and make it just as performant as MVC. I performed a string concatenation test several years ago against .NET 2.0

Comment: Yeah, we are re-doing in MVC, but it's a large app so could take a while.  Just trying to apply some bandages to key areas in the meantime.

Comment: @Paul from my recent benchmark between .net 4 (C#) and classic asp (VBScript), looping with concatenation was nearly 100x slower in classic asp.  These were for loops w/ concatenation on the same machine, and yes the variables were dimmed in classic asp.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox You can start in .net by only building one part of your current application in it, then slowly migrate each type of page as a new control in your .net app, and slowly it will all be migrating.  This is the route i'm currently taking, by using the .net site as a new IIS Application in the classic site.

Comment: Thanks Zee Tee. Between the answer and the comments that's some good info.

Comment: @ZeeTee: Most likely - they've had a good while to tailor and optimise since I ran those tests. ;o)  Also the [`GetString()`](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20409) function in Classic ASP is a real boon.